# Remove break links during user search in sidenav search menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

So on my website, I have a side navigation menu, and to break up sections I use `<br>`, but the problem is when you start searching, the break links will push the results all the way down as you search, and I need help to figure out a way to remove those ONLY when searching for something in the menu.

```
        <input type="text" id="navbar-search" placeholder="Search Menu" onkeyup="filterFunction()" autocomplete="on" autofocus>

        <ul id="sidenavList">
            <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Anthony</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Amira</a></li>

            <br>    <!-- I want these <br> to remove during search inquiry -->

            <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brock</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bryan</a></li>

            <br>    <!-- I want these <br> to remove during search inquiry -->

            <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Callie</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            function filterFunction() {
                var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
                input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                ul = document.getElementById("sidenavList");
                li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
                for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        li[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        li[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You might want to rethink that a little.  The way it is, if you type in "se" in the search input it will display the Section Titles, but if something else that does not match, then the section titles are excluded.  You need to make that consistent somehow (i.e. are those always in or out because it does not seem like you want to filger those unless maybe there are not matches.  Also <br> tags probably are not the best choice in that setting.  You usually do not set a "display" property to those tags, although I think you can..  A better desicription might halp.

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding jQuery to your code and use `<div>` instead of `<br>`.

```js
function filterFunction() {
  val = $('#navbar-search').val().toLowerCase();

  $('#sidenavList li').filter(function(){
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1)
  })
                
  if (val != '') {
    $('.not-allowed').parent().hide()
    $('.divider').hide()
  } else {
    $('.not-allowed').parent().show()
    $('.divider').show()
  }
}
```

```css
.divider {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="navbar-search" placeholder="Search Menu" onkeyup="filterFunction()" autocomplete="on" autofocus>

<ul id="sidenavList">
  <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Anthony</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Amira</a></li>

  <div class="divider">Here is the line break</div>

  <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Brock</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bryan</a></li>

  <div class="divider">Here is the line break</div>

  <li><a class="not-allowed" disabled>Section Title</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Callie</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: I always feel like an idiot posting a question, and then figuring it out an hour later, and then reading through these answers. Like I should've just thought about it first lol

Comment: Hi again, is it possible to be able to remove the "section titles" from being hoverable links? Every time I try something different it makes the search function stop and I'm not sure how to keep the search working while removing the section titles from appearing as links. Thanks :)

Comment: you can use `<label>` instead of `<a>`